# count the number of keys that map to a value

Tags: perl, hash, counting

I have the following hash

```
my %hash = (
    w1 => '0',
    e2 => '1',
    r1 => '2',
    o3 => '1',
    h4 => '0',
    t5 => '1',
);
```

I would like to get the number of keys that map to each value in the hash.

```
3 keys map to value 1.
1 key map to value 2.
2 keys map to value 0.
```

I would like to do this without using a function from a module.

One way I thought of doing this was looping through the values of the hash. If that value has a key then increment the counter for that key. The problem is knowing what the values are beforehand so that I can initialize counters for each value. There's probably an easier solution to this. I think regex might work.

attempt 1

```
my $string;
foreach my $value (value %hash) {
$string = join(",", $value);
}

# count the number of occurrences for each value (separated by commas)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another hash to count the occurrences.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = (
    w1 => '0',
    e2 => '1',
    r1 => '2',
    o3 => '1',
    h4 => '0',
    t5 => '1',
);

my %count;
for my $value (values %hash) {
    $count{$value}++;
}

for my $value (keys %count) {
    my $count = $count{$value};

    print "$count key", $count == 1 ? q() : 's',
          " map",       $count == 1 ? 's' : q(),
          " to $value.\n";
}
```

Comment: can you explain the syntax in the print statement? For example, what's `?` and `q()` and `'s'`? What's the `:` for?

Comment: `q()` is an empty string. `condition ? true : false` is the *ternary operator*, if the condition is true, it returns the true part, otherwise the false part. It handles the grammar in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the hash:

```
my %counterhash = ();

while ( ($key, $value) = each %hash )
{
  #print "key: $key, value: $hash{$key}\n";
  $counterhash{$value}++;
}
```

After that, `counterhash` will be a hash of each value to the number of occurrences of that value

You don't have to initialize a key of each particular `$value`. It is undefined initially, but is interpreted as zero when incremented.

The documentation says:

> The only things you need to declare in Perl are report formats and
>   subroutines (and sometimes not even subroutines). A variable holds the
>   undefined value ("undef") until it has been assigned a defined value,
>   which is anything other than "undef". When used as a number, "undef"
>   is treated as 0; when used as a string, it is treated as the empty
>   string, ""; and when used as a reference that isn’t being assigned to,
>   it is treated as an error.

Comment: that works too. can you show how you would initialize `$key` and `$value`? When I do `while ( my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {...}` it doesn't work for me. I get syntax errors.

Comment: not sure, I copied it from http://www.perlhowto.com/iterate_through_a_hash, because I don't really program in perl, so am not familiar with the syntax

Comment: LOL well in the end you posted a solution that works! +1, I'm sure more points are coming your way